# How to extract data from JSON in XSLT?

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I am calling a rest service in XSLT and in return getting JSON response .

How can I extract data from that JSON response using XSLT. Below is the XSLT code for calling the rest service and also given the JSON response. From JSON response I need to extract the values of `Cookie1`, `Cookie2` and `Cookie3`.

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:variable name="result1"> 
   <dp:url-open target="{$abc}" response="binaryNode" 
                resolve-mode="xml" data-type="xml" http-method="post">
   </dp:url-open>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="json">
  <xsl:value-of select="dp:decode(dp:binary-encode($result1/result/binary/node()), 
                                  'base-64' )" />
</xsl:variable>
```

**JSON Response:**

```
   {"mapData": 
     {
       "Cookie1": "KlzpP965iBw==",
       "status": "True",
       "Cookie2": "DDGT8mcsuzdMNNQ=",
       "Cookie3": "VERSION_4~mPpYUDcZnoJ0Z"
      }
   }
```

Please let me know how to do this using XSLT.

Comment: This is a duplicate of previous asked question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007280/how-to-convert-json-to-xml-using-xslt

Comment: Unless you use an XSLT 3.0 processor there is no built-in, standardized support, you should first check whether your XSLT processor (DataPower?) has some extension functions or instructions to deal with JSON data.

Comment: @SimonBlack:  That question is about converting JSON to XML in general.  This question is less ambitious: It just wants to know how to extract data from JSON using XSLT.  (I've fixed the title to reflect the actual question being asked.)

Answer (score 3):

### XSLT 3.0 / XPath 3.1

Use [`fn:parse-json()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-parse-json) to return a [`map`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#dt-map), then [`map:get()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-map-get) to get the values of interest.

Comment: Alternatively use fn:json-to-xml() to convert the JSON to a node tree, and use XPath expressions to select into the node tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:variable name="ValidationResponse">
<dp:url-open target="{$url}" 
             response="responsecode-binary" http-method="GET" 
             content-type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
             ssl-proxy="abc" http-headers="$headerValues" />
</xsl:variable> 

<dp:set-variable name="'var://context/sample/valResp'" 
                 value="normalize-space($ValidationResponse)"/>
```

Then convert the output using convert query params or other XSLT to get the desired output.