# split json to create multiple xml tags

Tags: json, xml

please let me know how we can convert below json request into multiple xml elements. Is it good to convert json into xml and then split xml based on Person tag and do processing or we can directly use json and convert it to output format
input request:

```
 {
 "Persons":{
 "Person": [
  {
 "LineID": 123456,
"Attributes": { "PersonMap": "Emp1,Emp2" },
"Department": 10
},
{
 "LineID": 123456,
"Attributes": { "PersonMap": "Emp3,Emp4" },
"Department": 20
}
]
 }
  }
```

output expected:

```
<Records>
 <EmpRec>
  <id>Emp1</id>
  <dept>10</dept>    
 </EmpRec>
 <EmpRec>
 <id>Emp2</id>
 <dept>10</dept>    
 </EmpRec>
 <EmpRec>
<id>Emp3</id>
<dept>20</dept>    
</EmpRec>
<EmpRec>
<id>Emp4</id>
<dept>20</dept>
</EmpRec>
</Records>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: what language/platform are you using?

Comment: trying to achieve it using xslt as am using apache camel as integration

Comment: as far as I know, xslt takes xml as input but you have a json.

Comment: agree, so the only option is to convert json into xml and then do xml to xml transformation using xslt?

Comment: I think so. There are some libraries and tools for converting json to xml, and even if it's not the exact xml output you need, it can then be processed by an xslt.

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007280/how-to-convert-json-to-xml-using-xslt

Comment: i am able to transform json to xml, but not sure who to convert to output format as need to create element based on input element values.