# Convert JSON to XML within XML Using XSLT 1.0

Tags: json, xml, xslt

How can you convert a JSON String Within XML to XML but using **XSLT 1.0**. The input xml would be like this:

```
<root>
    <element>
        <code>110</code>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
    <Datub>{"KLH":"A523","KSCH":"Z004","COMNS":"PCE","ECON":[{"KAB":1,"KBTR":0.00},{"KAB":100,"KBTR":-8.33},{"KAB":300,"KBTR":-15.00}]}</Datub>
    </element>
    <element>
    <code>111</code>
    <Currency>EUR</Currency>
    <Datub>{"KLH":"A","KSCH":"Z0","COMNS":"PCE","KEBIR":-0.00,"KONMA":"%","ECON":[{"KAB":1,"KBTR":0.00},{"KAB":100,"KBTR":-8.33},{"KAB":300,"KBTR":-15.00}]}</Datub>
    </element>
</root>
```

The output should look like this:

```
<root>
   <element>
        <code>110</code>
        <Currency>USD</Currency> 
        <Datub>
            <KLH>A</KLH>
            <KSCH>Z004</KSCH>
            <COMNS>PCE</COMNS>
            <KEBIR>-0.00</KEBIR>
            <KONMA>%</KONMA>
            <ECON>
                <element>
                    <KAB>1</KAB>
                    <KBTR>0.0</KBTR>
                </element>
                <element>
                    <KAB>100</KAB>
                    <KBTR>-8.33</KBTR>
                </element>
                <element>
                    <KAB>300</KAB>
                    <KBTR>-15.0</KBTR>
                </element>
            </ECON>
        </Datub>
    </element>
    <element>
        <code>111</code>
        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
        <Datub>
            <KLH>A</KLH>
            <KSCH>Z0</KSCH>
            <COMNS>PCE</COMNS>
            <KEBIR>-0.00</KEBIR>
            <KONMA>%</KONMA>
            <ECON>
                <element>
                    <KAB>1</KAB>
                    <KBTR>0.00</KBTR>
                </element>
                <element>
                    <KAB>100</KAB>
                    <KBTR>-8.33</KBTR>
                </element>
                <element>
                    <KAB>300</KAB>
                    <KBTR>-15.00</KBTR>
                </element>
            </ECON>
        </Datub>
    </element>
</root>
```

I tried out the solution at [How to convert json to xml using xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007280/how-to-convert-json-to-xml-using-xslt). It does have an example with stylesheet 1.0 but it does not not copy the json array fields and parent xml fields.

Comment: Here is something very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77015593/conversion-of-json-to-xml-using-xslt1-0 Try to adapt it to your case. If you don't succeed, post your best attempt  so that we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: If you know the names of the values you want to extract from the JSON, then this could be much easier.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 was defined in the previous century, long before JSON was even invented. Are you absolutely sure you can't move to a processor that supports a more recent version of the language?