JSON to XML using XSLT (base questions/13007280)
I manage a list of books with title, author and language. Sometimes a box ("coffret") contain many books.
I tried the XSLT code from questions/13007280 : it works quite well, but only for the title of each book...
I know basic XLST syntax but I cannot find where is the problem.
JSON file : (inside a xml structure)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sampleTag><![CDATA[
{
"book": [
{
"title" : "Hamlet: Modern text with introduction (The McGraw-Hill literature series)",
"Author" : "William Shakespeare",
"Language" : "en"
}
,
{
"title" : "Gilgamesh (French 'Edition' )",
"Author" : "de Anonymes",
"Language" : "fr"
}
,
{
"coffret" : [
{
"title" : "Milarepa (Poesie - Theatre)",
"Author" : "Eric-Emmanuel Schmitt",
"Language" : "fr"
}
,
{
"title" : "Oscar et la dame rose",
"Author" : "Éric-Emmanuel Schmitt",
"Language" : "fr"
} ]
}
,
{
"title" : "Otium: Art, éducation, démocratie",
"Author" : "Jean-Miguel Pire",
"Language" : "fr"
}
]
}
]]>
</sampleTag>

The XSLT code : (from questions/13007280 )
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:so="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007280"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs json so exsl">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" /> 

    <xsl:variable name="quot" select="'&quot;'" />
    <xsl:variable name="numbers" select="'0123456789'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="booleans" select="'tf'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:variable name="t1">
            <xsl:call-template name="object">
                <xsl:with-param name="json-in" select="." />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($t1)/so:output/*" mode="copy-sans-namespace" />  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy-sans-namespace">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy-sans-namespace" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="field">
        <!-- Input like: "Open": "25.15" bla -->
        <!-- output like: <so:output><Open>25.15</Open></so:output> <so:extra>bla</so:extra> -->
        <xsl:param name="json-in" />
        <xsl:variable name="field-name" select="substring-before(substring-after($json-in,$quot),$quot)" />
        <xsl:variable name="remainder" select="substring-after($json-in,':')" />
        <xsl:call-template name="value">
            <xsl:with-param name="json-in" select="$remainder" />
            <xsl:with-param name="parent-ele" select="$field-name" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="fields">
        <!-- Input like: "Open": "25.15" , "High": "25.15" } bla -->
        <!-- output like: <so:output><Open>25.15</Open><High>25.15</High></so:output> <so:extra>} bla</so:extra> -->
        <xsl:param name="json-in" />
        <xsl:variable name="n" select="normalize-space($json-in)" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring($n,1,1) = $quot">
                <xsl:variable name="t1">
                    <xsl:call-template name="field">
                        <xsl:with-param name="json-in" select="$n" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="t2" select="normalize-space( exsl:node-set($t1)/so:extra) " />
                <xsl:variable name="t3">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="substring($t2,1,1)=','">
                            <xsl:call-template name="fields">
                                <xsl:with-param name="json-in" select="substring-after($t2,',')" />
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$t2">
                            <so:extra><xsl:value-of select="$t2" /></so:extra>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>
                <so:output>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($t1)/so:output/* | exsl:node-set($t3)/so:output/*" />
                </so:output>
                <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($t3)/so:extra" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$n">
                <so:extra><xsl:value-of select="$n" /></so:extra>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="object">
        <!-- Input like: { X } bla -->
        <!-- output like: <so:output>fields(X)</so:output> <so:extra>bla</so:extra> -->
        <xsl:param name="json-in" />
        <xsl:param name="parent-ele" select="''" />
        <xsl:variable name="t1" select="normalize-space(substring-after($json-in,'{'))" />
        <xsl:variable name="t2">
                <xsl:call-template name="fields">
                <xsl:with-param name="json-in" select="$t1" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>  
        <xsl:variable name="t3" select="normalize-space(substring-after( exsl:node-set($t2)/so:extra, '}'))" />
        <so:output>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$parent-ele">
                    <xsl:element name="{$parent-ele}">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($t2)/so:output/node()" />
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>    
                    <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($t2)/so:output/node()" />
                </xsl:otherwise>    
            </xsl:choose>
        </so:output>
        <xsl:if test="$t3">
            <so:extra><xsl:value-of select="$t3" /></so:extra>
        </xsl:if>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="objects">
        <xsl:param name="json-in" />
        <xsl:param name="parent-ele" />
        <xsl:variable name="n" select="normalize-space($json-in)" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring($n,1,1) = '{'">
                <xsl:variable name="t1">
                    <xsl:call-template name="object">
                        <xsl:with-param name="json-in" select="$n" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="parent-ele" select="$parent-ele" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="t2" select="normalize-space( exsl:node-set($t1)/so:extra) " />
                <xsl:variable name="t3">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="substring($t2,1,1)='{'">
                            <xsl:call-template name="objects">
                                <xsl:with-param name="json-in" select="$t2" />
                                <xsl:with-param name="parent-ele" select="$parent-ele" />
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="substring($t2,1,1)=',' and substring(normalize-space(substring-after($t2,',')),1,1)='{'">
                            <xsl:call-template name="objects">
                                <xsl:with-param name="json-in" select="normalize-space(substring-after($t2,','))" />
                                <xsl:with-param name="parent-ele" select="$parent-ele" />
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$t2">
                            <so:extra><xsl:value-of select="$t2" /></so:extra>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>
                <so:output>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($t1)/so:output/* | exsl:node-set($t3)/so:output/*" />
                </so:output>
                <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($t3)/so:extra" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$n">
                <so:extra><xsl:value-of select="$n" /></so:extra>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="array">
        <!-- Input like: [ X1 X2 ] bla -->
        <!-- output like: <so:output><Y>X1</Y><Y>X2</Y></so:output> <so:extra>}bla</so:extra> -->
        <xsl:param name="json-in" />
        <xsl:param name="parent-ele" />
        <xsl:variable name="t1" select="normalize-space(substring-after($json-in,'['))" />
        <xsl:variable name="t2">
            <xsl:call-template name="objects">
                <xsl:with-param name="json-in" select="$t1" />
                <xsl:with-param name="parent-ele" select="$parent-ele" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>  
        <xsl:variable name="t3">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(substring-before(exsl:node-set($t2)/so:extra,']'),',')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after(exsl:node-set($t2)/so:extra,','))"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after(exsl:node-set($t2)/so:extra,']'))"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="t4">
            <xsl:element name="{$parent-ele}">
                <xsl:for-each select="$t2/so:output/*[local-name(.)=$parent-ele]">
                    <xsl:variable name="self" select="."/>
                    <xsl:variable name="tempResult">
                        <xsl:element name="{concat($parent-ele,'_element')}">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($self/*)" />
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($tempResult)"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="t5" select="exsl:node-set($t4)"/>
        <so:output>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$t5"/>
        </so:output>
        <xsl:if test="$t3">
            <so:extra><xsl:value-of select="$t3" /></so:extra>
        </xsl:if>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="value">
        <!-- Input like either array, object or string -->
        <!-- output like either array, object or string -->
        <xsl:param name="json-in" />
        <xsl:param name="parent-ele" />
        <xsl:variable name="first-letter" select="substring(normalize-space($json-in),1,1)" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$first-letter='{'">
                <xsl:call-template name="object">
                    <xsl:with-param name="json-in" select="$json-in" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="parent-ele" select="$parent-ele" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$first-letter='['">
                <xsl:call-template name="array">
                    <xsl:with-param name="json-in" select="$json-in" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="parent-ele" select="$parent-ele" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$first-letter=$quot">
                <xsl:call-template name="string">
                    <xsl:with-param name="json-in" select="$json-in" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="parent-ele" select="$parent-ele" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains($numbers,$first-letter)">
                <xsl:call-template name="number">
                    <xsl:with-param name="json-in" select="$json-in" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="parent-ele" select="$parent-ele"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains($booleans,$first-letter)">
                <xsl:call-template name="boolean">
                    <xsl:with-param name="json-in" select="$json-in" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="parent-ele" select="$parent-ele"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <so:output>ERROR</so:output>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="string">
        <!-- Input like: "X" bla -->
        <!-- output like: <so:output><Y>X</Y></so:output> <so:extra>bla</so:extra> -->
        <xsl:param name="json-in" />
        <xsl:param name="parent-ele" />
        <xsl:variable name="value" select="substring-before(substring-after($json-in,$quot),$quot)" />
        <xsl:variable name="remainder" select="normalize-space(substring-after(substring-after($json-in,$quot),$quot))" />
        <so:output>
            <xsl:element name="{$parent-ele}">
                <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
            </xsl:element>
        </so:output>
        <xsl:if test="$remainder">
            <so:extra><xsl:value-of select="$remainder" /></so:extra>
        </xsl:if>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="number">
        <!-- Input like: "X" bla -->
        <!-- output like: <so:output><Y>X</Y></so:output> <so:extra>bla</so:extra> -->
        <xsl:param name="json-in" />
        <xsl:param name="parent-ele" />
        <xsl:variable name="value">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(substring-before($json-in,','),'}')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($json-in,'}'))"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains(substring-before($json-in,','),']')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($json-in,']'))"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($json-in,','))"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="remainder">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(substring-before($json-in,','),'}')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('}',normalize-space(substring-after($json-in,'}')))"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains(substring-before($json-in,','),']')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(']',normalize-space(substring-after($json-in,']')))"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(',',normalize-space(substring-after($json-in,',')))"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>  
        <so:output>
            <xsl:element name="{$parent-ele}">
                <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
            </xsl:element>
        </so:output>
        <xsl:if test="$remainder">
            <so:extra><xsl:value-of select="$remainder" /></so:extra>
        </xsl:if>  
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="boolean">
        <!-- Input like: "X" bla -->
        <!-- output like: <so:output><Y>X</Y></so:output> <so:extra>bla</so:extra> -->
        <xsl:param name="json-in" />
        <xsl:param name="parent-ele" />
        <xsl:variable name="value">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(substring-before($json-in,','),'}')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($json-in,'}'))"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains(substring-before($json-in,','),']')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($json-in,']'))"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($json-in,','))"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="remainder">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(substring-before($json-in,','),'}')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('}',normalize-space(substring-after($json-in,'}')))"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains(substring-before($json-in,','),']')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(']',normalize-space(substring-after($json-in,']')))"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(',',normalize-space(substring-after($json-in,',')))"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>  
        <so:output>
            <xsl:element name="{$parent-ele}">
                <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
            </xsl:element>
        </so:output>
        <xsl:if test="$remainder">
            <so:extra><xsl:value-of select="$remainder" /></so:extra>
        </xsl:if>  
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

The command line :
java -jar saxon-he-11.6.jar -xsl:json2xml2.xsl -s:bibliothequeExtract.xml -o:bibliotheque2.xml
pause

The XML result :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
   <book_element>
      <title>Hamlet: Modern text with introduction (The McGraw-Hill literature series)</title>
   </book_element>
   <book_element>
      <title>Gilgamesh (French 'Edition' )</title>
   </book_element>
   <book_element>
      <coffret>
         <coffret_element>
            <title>Milarepa (Poesie - Theatre)</title>
         </coffret_element>
         <coffret_element>
            <title>Oscar et la dame rose</title>
         </coffret_element>
      </coffret>
   </book_element>
   <book_element>
      <title>Otium: Art, éducation, démocratie</title>
   </book_element>
</book>


Your stylesheet is written in XSLT 1.0. If you are using Saxon 11 you can take advantage of XSLT 3.0 which has many native tools for handling JSON.

I add a look at XSLT 3.0 online documentation (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/) ... need a real investment...

Here is an example of an XSLT 3.0 stylesheet:
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:json="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
exclude-result-prefixes="json">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/sampleTag">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="json:array" priority="1">
    <xsl:element name="{@key}s">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="json:array/json:map">
    <xsl:element name="{../@key}">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@key]">
    <xsl:element name="{@key}">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>

Given your example XML input, the result will be:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <books>
      <book>
         <title>Hamlet: Modern text with introduction (The McGraw-Hill literature series)</title>
         <Author>William Shakespeare</Author>
         <Language>en</Language>
      </book>
      <book>
         <title>Gilgamesh (French 'Edition' )</title>
         <Author>de Anonymes</Author>
         <Language>fr</Language>
      </book>
      <book>
         <coffrets>
            <coffret>
               <title>Milarepa (Poesie - Theatre)</title>
               <Author>Eric-Emmanuel Schmitt</Author>
               <Language>fr</Language>
            </coffret>
            <coffret>
               <title>Oscar et la dame rose</title>
               <Author>Éric-Emmanuel Schmitt</Author>
               <Language>fr</Language>
            </coffret>
         </coffrets>
      </book>
      <book>
         <title>Otium: Art, éducation, démocratie</title>
         <Author>Jean-Miguel Pire</Author>
         <Language>fr</Language>
      </book>
   </books>
</root>


Perfect ! Thank you ! From prehistory (where I was) with XSLT 1.0 to present time with XSLT 3.0...

I'm not sure I would even convert the JSON to XML. I think it's quite possible to tackle this by processing the JSON as a tree of maps and arrays.

@MichaelKay Go ahead and post an answer.

Here's how I would have tackled it. This produces very similar output.
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <books>
      <xsl:variable name="books" select="parse-json(sampleTag)?book"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$books?*">
        <book>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="?title">
               <xsl:call-template name="show-book"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <coffrets>
                <xsl:for-each select="?coffret?*">
                  <coffret>
                    <xsl:call-template name="show-book"/>
                  </coffret>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </coffrets>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </book>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </books>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template name="show-book">
    <title>{?title}</title>
    <Author>{?Author}</Author>
    <Language>{?Language}</Language>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

This solution is much more tightly coupled to the actual input structure. That might be a disadvantage, but it makes this coding pattern more useful if the output isn't quite so much an exact copy of the input, for example if the element names change or if extra processing needs to be added. Both styles have their uses.
In XSLT 4.0 it will become easier to combine this style with use of template rules, for example a template rule with match="record(title, Author, Language)" can be used to match JSON objects with this structure at different levels of the tree.

I chose to convert the JSON to XML because I believe that while XSLT 3.0 provides ways to query JSON directly (in fact, 3 different ways, IIRC), it does not have a method to process JSON. I think your answer illustrates this very well.

@michael.hor257k, what does "it does not have a method to process JSON" refer to exactly? You can match on XDM 3.1 arrays and maps, although not with parent/ancestor axis access as you are used to from XML.

It refers to the recursive processing that is at the heart of the XSLT processing model: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#rule-based-processing

That enable to add a serial number : <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
